# Google Maps V3 Rejecting My request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

AM trying to load google maps in the browser it keeps saying that

The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The "sensor" parameter specified in the request must be set to either "true" or "false".

What could be possibly wrong with my code?

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHlCzPPFeUds2erogWbvRZreRC3PX-BJE&sensor=FALSE">
    </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going on a limb here, but have you tried changing it to
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHlCzPPFeUds2erogWbvRZreRC3PX-BJE&sensor=false`<-- small case

Comment: Glad I can help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if it worked. Click on the tick mark under the down vote icon on this answer. Accepted Answers make me happy :)

Comment: Also avoid sharing api keys on public forums. Replace actualy kets with <KEY> when sharing links etc

Comment: There is no reason to avoid sharing these API keys. They are publicly available in the HTML page serving the map and can only be used on domains which the owner has allowed.  Some things do need to be protected, but these don't.

Comment: For google maps, yes. but say the habbit stays and people start sharing them for facebook, smtp services...etc which can actually be used to utilize the account to which they are bound. Its not exactly great practice